# In C#, is it possible to apply IContractResolver when coverting a POCO to a JObject?

Tags: c#, json, optimization, serialization, settings

Because we are in the middle of a migration, we can't hardcode some `JsonProperty` names into attributes on our DTO, but instead need to apply an `IContractResolver` to an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` in order to serialize the POCO correctly.

However, because I want to reuse code in an existing library, I'd rather convert my POCO to a JObject instead of a String.

Currently I am doing this:

```
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new()
            {
                ContractResolver = _salesforceContractResolver
            };
            string outboundContractJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outboundContract, settings);
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(outboundContractJson);
```

This works, but it is a bit inefficient.

I tried:

```
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new()
            {
                ContractResolver = _salesforceContractResolver
            };
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(outboundContractJson, settings);
```

But, not surprisingly, this does not compile.

I see that `JObject` offers the following signature:

`public static JObject FromObject(object o, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer);`

Is there an easy way to "convert" my settings to an instance of a serializer?

Or is there some other way I can/should do this?

Comment: Use `JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings)` to create serializer instance.

Comment: @Cinchoo, cheers!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  If you want to answer the question, I'll accept it.